# Implementing an macroeconomic model in Python's GEKKO

Tags: python, optimization, modeling, economics, gekko

This question is focussed somewhat on economic optimisation, and somewhat on python implementation, but maybe some in the community are able to help. I'm trying to implement a standard continuous-time macroeconomic savings model in Python's GEKKO platform, but haven't been able to get it to solve. I've taken the economic example provided in GEKKO's [documentation](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/apmonitor.com/wiki/uploads/Main/gekko.ipynb), and adapted to the basic savings decision model, but things are not quite working out. The model maximises the sum of utility from consumption, where consumption + investment = output. E.g. max integral(U(y-i)). Output y = k^ALPHA. investment = dk/dt+delta*k.

Can anyone tell why my code can't be solved? Is the platform even capable of solving such a model? I haven't seen many examples of economists using this platform to solve models, but not sure if this is because the platform is not suited or otherwise. It's a great platform and really keen to make it work if possible. Thank you in advance.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = GEKKO()
n=501
m.time = np.linspace(0,10,n)
ALPHA,DELTA = 0.333,0.99
i = m.MV(value=0)
i.STATUS = 1
i.DCOST = 0
x = m.Var(value=20,lb=0) # fish population
m.Equation(x.dt() == i-DELTA*x)
J = m.Var(value=0) # objective (profit)
Jf = m.FV() # final objective
Jf.STATUS = 1
m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
m.Equation(J.dt() == m.log(x**ALPHA-i))
m.Obj(-Jf) # maximize profit
m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
m.solve(disp=True) # Solve
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NaN` in the equation `dJ/dt = ln(x**ALPHA-i)`. When you include bounds `i>0` and `i<1`, the solver finds a solution.

[image: Solution]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = GEKKO()
n=501
m.time = np.linspace(0,10,n)
ALPHA,DELTA = 0.333,0.99
i = m.MV(value=0,lb=0,ub=1)
i.STATUS = 1
i.DCOST = 0
x = m.Var(value=20,lb=0) # fish population
m.Equation(x.dt() == i-DELTA*x)
J = m.Var(value=0) # objective (profit)
Jf = m.FV() # final objective
Jf.STATUS = 1
m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
m.Equation(J.dt() == m.log(x**ALPHA-i))
m.Obj(-Jf) # maximize profit
m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
m.solve(disp=True) # Solve

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,x.value)
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,i.value)
plt.ylabel('i')
plt.show()
```

Instead of `m.Obj()` (minimize) you can use the newer functions `m.Minimize()` or `m.Maximize()` to clarify the objective function intent. For example, you could switch to `m.Maximize(Jf)` to make it more readable.

There are also a couple other examples that may help you with [integral objectives (see solution 2)](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/IntegralObjective) and [economic dynamic optimization](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EconomicDynamicOptimization).

Comment: John - thanks for your time in answering my question. Just wondered if you know the reason why I need to bound the i variable? Best, Alex

Comment: The bounds help the solver find a solution. It helps the solver avoid guessing values such as `i=100` and then getting a `NaN` evaluation (and final objective) from the equation `J.dt() == m.log(x**ALPHA-i)`. You can adjust the bounds on `i` if you want it to be able to go negative. If you set the upper limit too high, it may get into `NaN` evaluations and the solver could get lost.